# Neither parameter or pointer

Tags: c, arrays

New to arrays and i keep getting the error that subscripted value is neither pointer or vector in selectLocation function. This is only the beginning of what is to be a tic tac toe program. What am i doing wrong?

```
void selectLocation(char board[],int choice);
void displayBoard(char[]);
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char board[3][3];
    int i;

    for (i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        displayBoard(board);
        selectLocation(board,i);
    }

return 0;
}

void displayBoard(char board[])
{
    printf("    0   1   2");
    printf("\n   --- --- --- ");
    printf("\n0 |   |   |   |");
    printf("\n   --- --- --- ");
    printf("\n1 |   |   |   |");
    printf("\n   --- --- --- ");
    printf("\n2 |   |   |   |");
    printf("\n   --- --- --- ");
}

void selectLocation(char board[],int choice)
{
    int x,y;

    printf("Enter a location for X or O in x,x format");
    printf("\nex. '0,1' '1,2'");
    scanf("%d,%d",&x,&y);

    if (choice%2==1)
    {
        board[x][y]='X';
    }
    else
    {
        board[x][y]='O';
    }
}
```

Comment: LearningC gives you the correct answer, another problem is that you don't check the result of `scanf` (you can have troubles if the user types "abc,def")

Answer (score 2):

```
board[x][y]='X';
```

board is not a 2D array, there for you are getting that error.

```
board[x]
```

is only valid. since you received a char array not 2D array.
So change the signature of function in both definition and declaration to receive 2D array,

```
void selectLocation(char board[][3],int choice)
{
    int x,y;
    ...
```

and

```
void displayBoard(char board[][3])
{
```

Comment: Now it shows array type has incomplete element type.

Comment: @BobbyII in which function?

Comment: @BobbyII ok. make that change. the 2nd index size must be specified